# Override ContentDefinition at RelyingParty Azure AD B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Can I override the `<ContentDefinition><LoadUri>` in a RP policy?

**RP Policy.xml**

```xml
<BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>mytenant.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TFExts</PolicyId>
</BasePolicy>
<BuildingBlocks>
    <ContentDefinitions>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.idpselections-ext-local">
        <LoadUri>~/tenant/default/idpSelector.cshtml</LoadUri>
      </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>
</BuildingBlocks>
```

**TFExts.xml**

```xml
<BuildingBlocks>
    <ContentDefinitions>
        <ContentDefinition Id="api.idpselections-ext-local">
            <LoadUri>https://localhost:44377/</LoadUri>
            <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
            <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:idpselection:1.0.0</DataUri>
            <Metadata>
                <Item Key="DisplayName">Idp selection page</Item>
                <Item Key="language.intro">Sign in</Item>
            </Metadata>
        </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>
</BuildingBlocks>
```

Comment: Yes, this should work. But knowing you and the question asked, is it not working?

Comment: Hey @OmerIqbal - it wasn't working but I was changing the wrong content id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was overwriting the **wrong** `ContentDefinition Id`.  So yes, I can override a `<ContentDefinition><LoadUri>` in a relying party policy.

```xml
<BuildingBlocks>
    <ContentDefinitions>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted-ext-local">
        <LoadUri>https://localhost:44377/</LoadUri>
      </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>
</BuildingBlocks>
```